# How to de-attach the specified element dynamically in MVVM +WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi  I am using wpf mvvm approach in my app.
I am getting this error:-

Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first. WPF

I have written code like this:-
In my xaml page :

```
<Border Background="White" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="bdrPdf">
    <ContentControl  x:Name="CntControlPdf"
        MouseDown="Img_MouseDownPdf"
        MouseMove="Img_MouseMovePdf"
        MouseUp="Img_MouseUpPdf"

        Width = "{Binding Path=ViewPageWidth}"
        Height = "{Binding Path=ViewPageHeight}"

        Content="{Binding Path=PDFViewWPFSource,ElementName=root}" >
    </ContentControl>
</Border>
```

In Code behind :-

```
public pdftron.PDF.PDFViewWPF PDFViewWPFSource
{
    get { return (pdftron.PDF.PDFViewWPF)GetValue(ImgSourcePropertyPDF); }
    set { SetValue(ImgSourcePropertyPDF, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PDFViewWPFSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImgSourcePropertyPDF =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PDFViewWPFSource", typeof(pdftron.PDF.PDFViewWPF), typeof(PageView), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(pdftron.PDF.PDFViewWPF)));
```

I am behindinf PDFtron control dynamically.
How can I solve this problem.
Where I have to written the code to de-attach this element.

Answer (score 1):

Your error simply means that in WPF, you cannot display the same UI element more than once at the same time. You have two choices... either you can remove one from the UI before adding it somewhere else, or you can fake it.

What I mean by faking it, is that you can *recreate* the UI element elsewhere, not actually duplicating the control. You can do that either by creating a new element of the same type to use instead, or you could display your UI element via a `DataTemplate` and `ContentControl`. Then you could just provide WPF with a new object of the same type with the same values and WPF will render it in the same way as the first, making it appear as if you had duplicated it.

---

UPDATE >>>

> thnks Sheridan, but I have to bind the ui element Like a data binding. How can I do this?I have add multiple control at runtime

In WPF, we don't data bind UI elements. Instead, we declare a data object (class) that contains the data for the element and then define a `DataTemplate` that will render the UI element. We then use the type of the data object as the data bound property. Take this simple example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourLocalPrefix:YourDataType}">
    <YourUiPrefix:PDFViewWPF DataContext="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then your property should look like this:

```
public YourDataType PDFViewWPFSource
{
    get { return (YourDataType)GetValue(ImgSourcePropertyPDF); }
    set { SetValue(ImgSourcePropertyPDF, value); }
}
```

Finally, display your UI element in a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PDFViewWPFSource}" />
```

The WPF framework will see the object of type `YourDataType`, find the relevant `DataTemplate` and render your control in place of the `ContentControl`.

Comment: Hi could you please tell where can init the Property.

Comment: I am binding PDFViewWPFSource to the content control.I have to remove all assigned PDFViewWPFSource  control before binding to the control.So please tell where can I init this control before binding. if am I am initializating to the PDFViewWPFSource =null in page of constructor.It's not working.so please tell me how can i remove before binding in control.

Comment: What do you mean by *`PDFViewWPFSource = null` ... is not working*? Setting the data bound property to `null` should clear all of the bindings.

Comment: yes PDFViewWPFSource = null It's not working. still I am getting this error:-Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

Comment: What type is `PDFViewWPFSource`? I mean, I can see that it is a `pdftron.PDF.PDFViewWPF`, but what is that? Is it a UI element? If so, *that* is your problem. You shouldn't have UI elements as data bound properties.

Comment: thnks Sheridan, but I have to bind the ui element Like a data binding. How can I do this?I have add multiple control  at runtime.

Comment: hi Sheridan,could you please tell me,How can bind the UI control in Contenttemplate